# Will cost only getting the size of a collection of 1000 docs as 1000 read?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am confused about Cloud firestore cost. I want to get the size of a collection of 1000 docs, and I am not reading every doc data, so will it cost me as 1000 read or 1 read?

```
db.collection(`users/${user}/followers`)
.get().catch(onErr).then(followers=> {
  console.log('followers length: ', followers.size);
});
```

I have 1000 docs in `followers` collection, so as you can see I am only reading the length of collection, so how much will cost me ?? 1000 read or 1 read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in the `followers` collection you have 1000 document then it will cost you 1000 reads. Here you are attaching the method `get()` which retrieves all the documents in a collections

Comment: As an addition, it would be more efficient to have a counter with the number of documents in that collection rather than counting them all again and again.

Comment: Is there a way to get the size of collection without costing `1000 read`, because actually I dont need all doc data, I just want to see how many followers a user have and not reading all followers data

Comment: @Muhammad since firebase has both realtime and firestore, when you add a document to a collection in firestore at the beginning. Create a node that will have the same name as the collection in the realtime database and under it add a counter. Whenever you add a new document update the counter by 1 in the realtime database. Then if you just want the size you can retrieve the counter from realtime database. This way it won't cost you anything since the realtime database price is based on storage