# How to decrease firestore read operations?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I Have a chat app, and I need to match **user contacts**, with **users collections**.

```
// assume there is 100 contacts
const phoneContacts = {"91302034403": "Salman", "xxx": "xxx"};

// assume there is 30 contacts
const contactsUsingMyApp = ["91302034403", "xxx"];

// assume there is 30000 users
const snap = await db.collection('users').get();
const docs = snap.docs;

for (let i = docs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   
    const data = docs[i].data();
    const phone = data.phone;

    if (phoneContacts[phone] !== undefined){
      contactsUsingMyApp.push(phone);
    }
       
}
```

**What is the problem ?**

1. I have 30000 users in **users collection**.
2. Every day **200 new users** install **my app**
3. The above code **executes**. only in **sign-up**

**Now let's calculate**

1. `200 x 30000 = 6000000 read operations` **per day**
2. `$0.06/100000 reads`
3. `6000000/100000 = 60 * $0.06 * 30day = $108/m`

The above also is scalable and calculated only for **read operations** and that is really expensive, How can I decrease it, until I can remain with firebase?

Why I am reading the entire collection for any **sign-up** ? Because there is one request in **sign-up**.

Why I am not seeking the user contacts like below as there is a very less operations than above, because there is **many requests**

```
// assume there is 100 contacts
const phoneContacts = {"91302034403": "Salman", "xxx": "xxx"};    

const phonesArray = Object.keys(phoneContacts);

for (let i = phonesArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   
    const snap = await db.collection('users')
    .where("phone", "==", phonesArray[i]).get();

    if (snap.size > 0){
      // this contact is registered with this app
    }
       
}
```

**No as you can see, there is many request, as we are requesting within the loop.**

Comment: If you only want certain documents from the collection, it seems like you want to add a filter on your query, as described in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you, I used that way, but like that I have to request many times, for example if a users have 300 contacts on his devise, then there would be 300 request and that really takes time

Comment: Yeah, that's the cost of reading documents. If you don't want to read them again, then store them locally

Comment: Echoing @DougStevenson : this is a *common* reason Redux is used with Firestore - you can setup a Listener for *changes* to a set of documents, but all local *use* of the documents come from the Redux store.  The only read is when the app starts.  You *could* go farther than this using local storage, but then you'd need to handle a lot of cache conditions.  *Not* impossible; the need depends on your usage patterns

Comment: Another point: *do* you actually need to match those contacts at sign-up?  If you only query/filter at need you can reduce this greatly.

Comment: Just a thought on this statement; *users have 300 contacts on his devise, then there would be 300 request*. If your data is structured correctly, that would be one request with 300 results which would take .049s to complete.

Comment: Also, and I may not be understanding the intention, but it appears when the user logs in you want to know which of the existing firebase users are already in their contact list. If so, then perhaps the approach could be more efficient; if a user has 100 phone numbers in their contact list, why read in 30,000 users to see if they are a match? You should iterate over the 100 phone numbers in the users contacts and and query for those only. Right? That would make the queries trivial and very small amount of reads

Comment: @LeadDreamer, yeah this code only executes on sign-up, means once per install.

Comment: @Jay, Yeah Users may have 100 contacts, may have 300 contacts, then on the way I request every user in server then will be `requests = contact lists`

Comment: I still ask: **WHY** do the users "...want to know which of the existing firebase users are already in their contact list..."?  What do they do with this information?  Is it just a number?  Could it be updated over time?  Do they want to reach out to one of them?  If there is no actual *use* for this information, why do it?

Comment: If you just query for the number of phone numbers in each users contacts list, that changes the entire picture; so instead of 600k reads per day it would be 200 users * 100 contacts = 20k. Big difference in speed and cost. Also, reading in 30k worth of user node data could overwhelm the device so that's probably not a good approach.

Comment: @LeadDreamer, I am loading all users from server to client device only and only to avoid multiple request.

Comment: @Jay, please see the question again, I have added some more infos

Comment: @LeadDreamer, please see the question again, I have added some more infos

Comment: @DougStevenson, please see the question again, I have added some more infos

Comment: Looks like the question was closed but I will re-itereate, if the user has 100 contacts, there's no point in loading all contacts from your database. Just perform 100 queries to see if any of the users match. It's unlikely all 100 will match so it will be some number less than 100. That's going to be your fastest result with the lowest cost.

Comment: @Jay, You mean if there is no match then there is no cost and no time for unmatched contacts ?

Comment: Look at the Firestore pricing [Document reads: $0.06 per 100,000 documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#select-region). You're reading in 600,000 documents to make those matches when you really only need 100 (or less). Reading 600,000 documents will take 'longer' than querying 100 (or less). Lastly, if that 600,000 grows to double or triple the size, reading in that much data will overwhelm your device and cause a poor user experience. As I mentioned above, why read a huge chunk of data when you only are interested in a small subset.

Comment: @Jay, I mentioned only because of avoiding multi requests. You know If I get the entire `collection: users` there is one request to server. but if match all contacts with server data, there is 100 request to server. more request will take more time

Comment: Just trying to help here, but that's not at all accurate. Please review the billing link in my above comment and also review the documentation example for [Total usage by user task](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example#costs-breakdown). Lastly sending 600,000 documents to your app from the server will take far more time than querying for 100 or less documents. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367032/will-cost-only-getting-the-size-of-a-collection-of-1000-docs-as-1000-read)

Answer (score 1):

The [`in` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) might allow you to achieve this with less reads per user, however as the in query takes a maximum of 10 values you need to check the contacts in chunks:

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, size), ...chunk(arr.slice(size), size)] : [];

const contactsWithApp = Promise.all(
  chunk(Object.keys(phoneContacts)).map(
     it => db.collection("users").where("phone", "in", it).get()
  )
).flat();
```

Alternatively you could cache all users in your application and update the cache once in a while:

```
let phones = new Set();

async function updateCache() {
 phones = new Set();
 (await db.collection("users").get()).forEach(user => phones.add(user.phone));
}

const contactsWithApp = Object.keys(phoneContacts).filter(it => phones.has(it));
```

Comment: I wish this was an option! Unfortunately the `in` query only supports 10 comparison values - however, perhaps looping and doing 10 at a time would suffice?

Comment: ah, indeed, what an arbitrary limitation ...

Comment: @JonasWilms, thank you very much. Your second option is same as mine, because my code also executes ones per install, because I am not reading the entire collection all the time. but there is may between 100 to 200 install per day.

Comment: This is supposed to be serverside ... or are you actually loading all your app users contacts onto every device?

Comment: @JonasWilms if it's client-side, that could raise serious security issues.

Comment: @JonasWilms, for now as you can see my code, Yes I am loading all users from server into my all users devices. just because of avoiding more request and a fast lauch.

because if I iterate over users contacts and then request to server there the requests will be eqaual to users contacts, and that gets to more time.

Comment: Privacy and security concerns apart (you should really not do this clientside btw), having to do an extra request for every 10 users seems to be a very arbitrary limit of firebase. If you run your own server in front of it (or on top of another database), you can compare all contacts with one request, and having an in-memory cache (the Set) makes this very efficient, also in that scenario the data of other users stays on your server and doesn't get exposed to end users

Comment: Voted up for the first part, and that looks a solution near to my problem

Comment: @JonasWilms,  please see the question again, I have added some more infos

Comment: @JonasWilms could you please once again check your first part of code ? because for there is an error: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`